# Connect GitHub and gitlab with different mailboxes, set up SSH respectively, Github succeeds, gitlab fails

Tags: ssh, gitlab

I want to use one email to connect to GitHub, another email link GitLab.

GitHub's connection is successful, but GitLab keeps prompting for a password, and the password input is always there.

I have generated an SSH keys separately for each services, this is the files:

[image]

This is the config file:

[image: config]

这个是执行: This is the execution:

```
ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com
```

Result:

[image: execution]

How can I get past this error?

Hope successfully connect to gitlab

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include configuration and logs as text in your answer, not screenshots.

Comment: It looks like the correct key if offered, but gitlab doesn't accept it. Did you add it correctly?

Comment: Yes, I have referred to several technical blogs and repeated operations several times, but still failed, please tell me what additional information should be provided, thank you

Comment: I'm not sure. It's either that you mixed up the keys (either github/gitlab or public/private) or your key requires password and is not unlocked (I don't use password for my ssh keys, living on the edge)

Answer (score 0):

The logs show that the right key is  proposed to GitLab.

Make sure that:

- your `~/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab` is not passphrase-protected (not encrypted), for testing
- your `~/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab.pub` public key has been registered to your GitLab account SSH settings page, as one continuous line.

Comment: I'm sure these are correct

Comment: Would [this sshd_config change](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/openssh-slow-at-ssh2_msg_service_accept-received/) help?

Comment: This problem seems to be different from mine

Comment: Can you add `User git` in your `Host gitlab.com` section? And try `ssh -Tv gitlab.com`? (Without the `git@`)

Comment: I finished it but didn't success yet

Comment: I just re-did this article exactly and it still fails

Comment: I haven't enter a passphrase when generating the keys

Comment: @AriaGeng Would [altssh.gitlab.com](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/) work better (port 443) ?

Comment: Permission is still denied

Comment: Can you show us the current config file, using altssh?

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK3Q7.png

Comment: @AriaGeng I am starting to suspect SSH egress is somehow blocked access to GitLab, as illustrated by [this article](https://theintercept.com/2023/01/26/apple-china-censorship-hong-kong-gitlab/).